# Как вывести из класса данные

Tags: python, ооп

Пытаюсь разобраться в  ООП и набросал класс, который принимает два числа, затем он должен их помножить, затем разделить и в конце результаты из этих двух методов вывести на экран

```
class Numbers_Class:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def multiply(self):
        self.value1*self.value2

    def devision(self):
        self.value1/self.value2

    def get_list(self):
        return [self.value1, self.value2]

num_class = Numbers_Class(10, 5)

print(num_class.get_list())
```

В итоге он выводит [10, 5], а хочу получить [50, 2]. Как мне это сделать?

Суть всех этих действий, хочу написать класс , в котором будет кучу методов, в него я буду при инициализации передавать данные и за тем хотелось бы вызвать один метод get_list() лист с данным, в котором будет сгруппированная информация от каждого метода. Как заставить методы выполнятся в классе? Чтобы я в чудо- аппарат заливал грубо говоря молоко и засыпал сахар, а на выходе получал мороженое. не вызывая промежуточные методы, не нажимал кнопку, заморозить молоко, перемешать сахар с молоком и так далее, а чтобы класс сам их вызывал.

Comment: Уточнил свой вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Numbers_Class:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def get_list(self):
        return [self.value1*self.value2, int(self.value1/self.value2)]

num_class = Numbers_Class(10, 5)

print(num_class.get_list())
```

С учетом вашего последнего комментария:

```
class Numbers_Class:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def multiply(self):
        return self.value1*self.value2

    def devision(self):
        return self.value1/self.value2

    def get_list(self):
        return [self.multiply(), self.devision()]
```

Comment: Суть моего вопроса, как мне вызываеть методы, после иницилизации класса? То есть я пиши вот так num_class = Numbers_Class(10, 5) и затем только так print(num_class.get_list()) и все методы выполняются внутри класса, короче метод деления и умножения запускается после иницилизвции класса и в коцнуе забираю данные get_list()

Comment: вместо `int(a/b)`, автор вероятно хотел `a // b`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Методы класса не выполняются сами по себе. Их мало написать, нужно ещё и запустить после того, как экземпляр класса создан.

Например так:

```
num_class = Numbers_Class(10, 5)
num_class.multiply()
num_class.devision()
print(num_class.get_list())
```

2. В добавок к этому у вас ещё неправильно написаны методы multiply и devision. В них производятся вычисления, но результат этих вычислений вообще никак не используется и ни на что не влияет.

Результат нужно куда-то записать. Например так:

```
self.value1 = self.value1 * self.value2
```

3. Впрочем, даже если вы так перепишете свои методы, вы получите не совсем то, что хотели. Потому что после выполнения метода multiply() уже изменится значение value1 и в последующем выполнение метода devision() будет использовано уже новое значение 50.

Тут нужно пересмотреть логику. Как вариант, можно использовать отдельную пару переменных для хранения исходных значений, и ещё одну пару - для текущих.

UPD: С учётом вашего комментария можно сделать так:

```
class Numbers_Class:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.value1 = param1 * param2
        self.value2 = param1 / param2

    def get_list(self):
        return [self.value1, self.value2]
```

Comment: Нельзя сделать так, чтобы при входе было два числа, и после иницилизации класса я туда передал два числа и сделал просто get_list  и получил лист с делеными и помножеными числами. Наверное я не правильно формулирую вопрос. Можно ли, чтобы класс стал одним большим методом, то есть чтобы методы деления и умножения выполнялись внутри него?

Comment: Тогда можно вообще обойтись без лишних методов, и все вычисления сделать в init. Сейчас я дополню свой ответ кодом.